# checking for DB4 major version... configure: error: Header contains different version

Tags: php, configuration, compilation, berkeley-db

I've been trying to cmpile PHP with following `./configure`

[./configure]

```
`CC="gcc -m64" ./configure \
  --prefix=/opt/php-5.3.14 \
  --with-apxs2=/opt/apache-httpd-2.2.22/bin/apxs \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --enable-intl \
  --libdir=/usr/lib \
  --with-icu-dir=/usr \
  --with-gettext=/usr \
  --with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre-8.35 \
  --with-pcre-dir=/opt/pcre-8.35 \
  --with-readline=/usr \
  --with-libxml-dir=/usr/bin/xml2-config \
  --enable-soap \
  --enable-wddx \
  --with-xmlrpc \
  --with-xsl=/usr \
  --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
  --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
  --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
  --enable-dba \
  --with-db4=/usr　\
  --with-zlib=/opt/zlib-1.2.8 \
  --with-zlib-dir=/opt/zlib-1.2.8 \
  --with-gd \
  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
  --with-png-dir=/usr \
  --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
  --enable-gd-native-ttf \
  --enable-gd-jis-conv \
  --with-mcrypt=/usr \
  --enable-bcmath \
  --with-openssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.0g \
2>&1 | tee configure_log.txt`
```

I've got message `checking for DB4 major version... configure: error: Header contains different version`

Tell me how to fixe this plobram.

Packages of db4 are the below.

```
# rpm -qa|grep db4
db4-devel-4.7.25-18.el6_4.x86_64
db4-cxx-4.7.25-18.el6_4.x86_64
db4-4.7.25-18.el6_4.x86_64
db4-utils-4.7.25-18.el6_4.x86_64
#
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have both db4 and db5 installed, and /usr/include/db.h
is *NOT* from db-4.7.25.

Try adding -I/usr/include/db47 to CFLAGS so that /usr/include/db47/db.h
is found before /usr/include/db.h